# Open and Read a text file Located in a SharePoint Document Library using CSOM

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sharepoint

I'm able to get the relative path to a file in SharePoint. I now need to open the file and read its contents. This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to open a file for reading unless it is local to my hard drive, which it is not. Here is my code:

```
If item.FieldValues("File_x0020_Type") = "html" Then
    Dim the_file As SP.File = oWebsite.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(item.FieldValues("FileRef"))
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(the_file)  
    Dim sr As StreamReader = StreamReader(the_file)
    textbox1.text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry misread that.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://SpSiteUrl");
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, "thisFile");

System.IO.Stream stream = fileInfo.Stream;

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream))
     string line;
     while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         System.Console.WriteLine (line);  
     }
}
```

Once it is set to the Stream, you should be able to loop through it normally.

I also saw this second method.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))  {
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, "thisFile");
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(getItem))
     {                  
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
     }
}
```

Then you would just loop through the fileStream normally as well.

Here is a second way to loop as well -

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream)) 
{
      while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
      {
             Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
      }
}
```

And actually, now that I am reading your question one more time - you might be able to do just this.

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)  
textbox1.text = reader.ReadToEnd()
reader.Close()
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, OpenBinaryStream is not part of CSOM. I believe that is if you are running on the SharePoint server. I'm connecting via a client machine and there is no OpenBinaryStream.

Comment: You most certainly can - http://mosstouch.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-client-object-model_3.html

Comment: If you look at the very end of your link, client code does not have OpenBinaryStream. It looks like I need to use OpenBinaryDirect, however It doesn't explain how to interact with the data stream.